# Cannot connect from inside docker swarm cluster to external mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, docker-compose, docker-swarm

If I run single docker container of my backend, it runs well and connects to mongodb which is running on host. But when I run my backend using docker-compose, it doesn't connect to mongodb and prints to console:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [12.345.678.912:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to 12.345.678.912:27017 timed out]
```

docker-compose.yml contents:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: __BE-IMAGE__
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 2048M
    ports:
      - "1337:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "1340:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

how I run single docker container:

```
docker run -p 1337:8080 BE-IMAGE
```

Comment: Can you show the docker compose file contents, and how you start the single container?

Comment: @MiguelMarques updated question

Comment: typically you launch mongo using same docker-compose.yaml file ... you are not so above assumes mongo is launched independently prior to above ... is this what you are doing ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I don't use docker to launch mongodb. I run it on host as ussual.

Answer (score 0):

you need to link the mongo port since localhost is not the same from inside versus outside the containers

```
ports:
  - "1337:8080"
  - "27017:27017"
```

On port definitions left hand side is outside, right side is internal to your container ... Your error says internal to your container it cannot see port 27017 ... above is just linking that mongo port so the container can access that port outside of docker

Comment: "1337:8080" - it is BACKEND port
I have already written that mongodb runs on HOST, NOT IN DOCKER.